# grid-template-columns alternatives

Tags: visual-studio, css, css-grid

When I try to use "grid-template-columns" and "grid-column-gap" a green line appears under them and says it's not a known CSS 3 property. Also, IE and Firefox cant compile the site well. My IDE is **visual studio 201**5 here comes my code:

```
.gridContainer{
    display:grid;

    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
    padding-top:150px;

    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    padding-bottom:150px;
}
.grid-item {

background-color: #99e4f5;

border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

font-size: 17px;
text-align: center;
border: 5px solid #ffffff;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px grey;


color: #676363;
```

Are there any alternatives to using?

thanks,

Saeed

Comment: When you say '*a green line appears...*', I assume you're using an IDE; could you add that to your tags for the question? Also what version are you using, is there an update available? Because, so far as I can tell, your code works ([JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1d3p5fwq/)); so changing your code to satisfy your IDE seems unwise.

Comment: in addtion to what @DavidThomas said, some IDE and even online tools aren't up to date and consider some new properties invalid but this is not an issue. You simply need to consider browser support and don't bother yourself with those warnings.

Comment: Are you sure these lines aren't just your IDE's way to mark some elements you're currently working on?

Comment: Thanks for your notification. My IDE is VisualStudio 2015. The IDE accept the code but informs me it's not a known CSS property name. Also, the site can't get appear in firefox and IE.

Comment: Well, grid system is new. Browsers implemented it a year ago so I doubt VS2015 is a good IDE to work with grid.

Comment: IE also uses an older version of the grid syntax too but FF should be fine.